# .append() in jquery doesn't work for divs

Tags: jquery

```
$(".plp").click(function() {
    var title = $(this).siblings('h2').clone();
    var albom = $(this).siblings('span').clone();
    var image = $(this).siblings('img').clone();
    var price = $(this).siblings('.item_cost,h4').clone();
    $("#cart_added_items").append(image);
    $("#cart_added_items").append(title);
    $("#cart_added_items").append(albom);
    $("#cart_added_items").append(price);
```

I want to appand this variables in different divs. when I write `$("#cart_added_items").append("<div>"+image+"</div>");`

output is: `[object Object]`

Comment: **.append()** in jquery *does* work for divs

Comment: This is a Typo since it isn't found in the js code

Comment: yep, use image.html()

Comment: maybe better use `appendTo()`?

Answer (score 3):

`image` contains a jQuery object and you are using it in string concatenation so it's converted to string (and object.toString() gives you [object Object]).

Correct version would be:

```
$("#cart_added_items").append( $("<div/>").append(image));
```